# How to write a Jasmine Unit Test for addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I couldn't figure out how could I write a Jasmine unit test for AddEventListener? How do I test the following code if the addEventListener is working?

```
private static disableScrollingOnPageWhenPanelOpen(): void {
window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', PhoneInputComponent.preventDefault, { passive: false });
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', PhoneInputComponent.preventDefault, { passive: false });
window.addEventListener('touchmove', PhoneInputComponent.preventDefault, { passive: false });}
```

This is what I've tried but it wasn't working.

```
describe('disableScrollingOnPageWhenPanelOpen', () => {
it('should disable DOMMouseScroll', () => {
  const e = new Event('DOMMouseScroll');
  PhoneInputComponent['disableScrollingOnPageWhenPanelOpen']();
  window.dispatchEvent(e);       
  spyOn(window, 'addEventListener').and.callThrough();
  expect(window).toHaveBeenCalledWith('e',
    PhoneInputComponent['preventDefault'], { passive: false });
});
```

Could anyone help me with this? I was gonna test if the addEventListener has been called but I'm not sure if the method I'm using is the right approach to test the code.

Comment: Did your test case pass? Is there any error?

Comment: @slideshowp2 It gave an error:

`Error: <toHaveBeenCalledWith> : Expected a spy, but got <global>.
        Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...arguments)`

Answer (score 0):

`expect(window)`, this line `window` is not a spy.

Try changing the line to:

```
expect(window.addEventListener).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith('e',
    PhoneInputComponent['preventDefault'], { passive: false });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I realized I made a mistake in my code, which is I added "not" in front of the "toHaveBeenCalledWith".

The test failed when I change the line to 

`expect(window.addEventListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith('e',
    PhoneInputComponent['preventDefault'], { passive: false });`

The Error Message:
`Expected spy addEventListener to have been called with:
          [ 'e', Function, Object({ passive: false }) ]
        but it was never called.`

Comment: as the addEventListener was never called to begin with in my code. The code i was testing was simply adding the "addEventListenet" and not calling it.

**How can I test if the addEventListener is being added?**

Comment: I would do something like this `const addEventListenerSpy = spyOn(window, 'addEventListener'); ... expect(addEventListenerSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();` to see if the addEventListener was called.